# Creating a new div every time my mouse is idle?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a div when I go idle on my mouse position. Right now when it is idle it creates a new div on my mouse position. How can I make it so it creates a new div on my new mouse position when I go idle while keeping the previous div? Many thanks!

```js
var idleTimer = null;
var idleState = false;
var idleWait = 2000;
var idleInterval = 1000;
var idleStartTime = Date.now();
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;

(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //Set a interval that checks the idle state
    setInterval(function() {
      if (idleState == true) {
        //add element if it doensn't excist, otherwise update it
        if ($('#idleDiv').length === 0) {
          var $el = $('<div>');
          $el.attr('id', 'idleDiv');
          $el.css('left', mouseX);
          $el.css('top', mouseY);

          $el.html('<p>You\'ve been idle for ' + ((Date.now() - idleStartTime) / 1000) + ' seconds.</p>');
          $("body").append($el);
        } else {
          $('#idleDiv').html('<p>You\'ve been idle for ' + ((Date.now() - idleStartTime) / 1000) + ' seconds.</p>');
        }
        //change the height when idle
        $('#idleDiv').height($('#idleDiv').height() + 10);
      }
    }, idleInterval);

    //sets the idleState to false on mousemove events and to true when no mouse move happended for 'idleWait' milliseconds.
    $(document).on('mousemove', function(event) {
      idleStartTime = Date.now();
      idleState = false;

      clearTimeout(idleTimer);

      idleTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        idleState = true
      }, idleWait);

      //Set the mouse coordinates
      mouseX = event.pageX;
      mouseY = event.pageY;
    });
  });
})(jQuery)
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#idleDiv {
  background-color: gray;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a working example, I'm just guessing.

I think my previous attempt might have created the `div`s you wanted but they were missing the css positioning information as they had different `id`.
Also, one of the lines modified `$el` after it had been added to the document so those changes probably had no effect.

I've made another attempt below, which adds the `position: absolute` to each element being added. And modifies the newly added element similarly to your original code by adding a randomish id to each new element.

```
var idleTimer = null;
var idleState = false;
var idleWait = 2000;
var idleInterval = 1000;
var idleStartTime = Date.now();
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;

(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //Set a interval that checks the idle state
    setInterval(function() {
      if (idleState == true) {
        //add element if it doensn't excist, otherwise update it
        var $el = $('<div>');
        var randomid = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
        $el.attr('id', randomid);
        $el.css('left', mouseX);
        $el.css('top', mouseY);
        $el.css('position', 'absolute');
        $el.css('background-color', 'grey');
        $el.html('<p>You\'ve been idle for ' + ((Date.now() - idleStartTime) / 1000) + ' seconds.</p>');
        $("body").append($el);
        //change the height when idle
        $('#'+randomid).height($('#'+randomid).height() + 10);
      }
    }, idleInterval);

    //sets the idleState to false on mousemove events and to true when no mouse move happended for 'idleWait' milliseconds.
    $(document).on('mousemove', function(event) {
      idleStartTime = Date.now();
      idleState = false;

      clearTimeout(idleTimer);

      idleTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        idleState = true
      }, idleWait);

      //Set the mouse coordinates
      mouseX = event.pageX;
      mouseY = event.pageY;
    });
  });
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: the div does not seem to be created. It does, however, create a new timer and on a new location just not where my mouse is.